# Dictionary value extract

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a list with dict like following

```
[[{1:'a',2:'b'},{1:'g',2:'y'}],[{1:'r',2:'i'},{1:'t',2:'o'},{1:'q',2:'e'}],[{1:'p',2:'f'}]]
```

I want to extract output value as follows

```
a g - first value of first list
b y -second value of first list
r t q - first value of second list
i o e - second value of second list
p - first value of third list
f- second value of third list
```

I want output like
Could anyone suggest how can I do this?

Comment: list seems a little short to extrapolate a pattern. Also as a sidenote, if this is homework, use the appropriate homework tag

Comment: do the dictionaries only ever have ```1``` and ```2``` as keys?

Comment: yes, all dictionaries have the same keys (need not be 1 and 2 but it'll be the same always)

Answer (score 5):

If the dictionaries only ever have `1` and `2` as keys you could do this:

```
lst = [[{1:'a',2:'b'},{1:'g',2:'y'}],[{1:'r',2:'i'}]]
for i in lst:
    for k in (1, 2):
        print(*[j.get(k, '') for j in i])
```

Output:

```
a g
b y
r
i
```

Edit: or if you don't know your keys in advance:

```
keys = {k for i in lst for j in i for k in j}
for i in lst:
    for k in keys:
        print(*[j.get(k, '') for j in i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more robust solution if the dictionaries have keys other than `1` and `2`:

```py
def f(l):
  all_keys = []
  for e in l:
    for d in e:
      for i in d:
        if i not in all_keys:
          all_keys += [i]
  for e in l:
    for k in all_keys:
      print(*(d.get(k, '') for d in e))

f([[{1:'a',2:'b'},{1:'g',2:'y'}],[{1:'r',2:'i'},{1:'t',2:'o'},{1:'q',2:'e'}],[{1:'p',2:'f'}]])
```

Output:

```
a g
b y
r t q
i o e
p
f
```

Comment: it is faster to do ```for i in d``` than ```for i in d.keys()```, also you can set the default value in ```get``` to ```''``` so you can do ```[d.get(k, '') for d in e]```

Comment: @Nin17 OK point taken. I edit my code with your suggestion

Comment: @Nin17 It working fine for me: [run code here](https://tio.run/##dc5BDsIgFATQfU/xdx@UmKgb08STNI2pASopAUQ2jenZEWirLnT5ZoDBjeFmzfHkfIxcSJBE07oC6LS@DGJ8wBmaNllaDwKUAZ3b2TxbzJ4TlRO@JgBKpsjYkOP1xU/7tbJNM@rfzvDruvPKBLIhfNeLQAYGiPTrV5RWlSRN89zX2CE71HjFiWX1RSNOLSutL1ZLG4rsonuReJ91xTK5pTG@AA)

Comment: ok yep it does, my bad